# how to load special character string in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, etl

## Problem

I am trying to load string from flat file into SSIS but it gives me error due to it contains specials character but I want to load it and store it as it is into the destination table. How can I do thi.

## Example Strings

> https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/745647/escape-characters-for-and-in-concatenated-expressions#bm1821725
>
> Space Aviator Wired Ultimate Headphones (Inline Mic) - Black/Red

## Error

> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: Flat File Destination.Inputs[Flat File Destination Input].Columns[c.links_product_list_url] has lineage ID 214 that was not previously used in the Data Flow task.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "Flat File Destination" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.

Comment: The problem is not with the string that you are trying to process, it is that the metadata of your component has changed.  Double click the flatfile destination and this will refresh the metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you provided:

> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "Flat File Destination" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".

Shows up that the metadata of the destination flat file is changed.

*You have to check your columns name and codepages , Row delimiter , Column delimiter ,...*

**Fixing this issue**

Just open your package in visual studio, if no expression is used in destination flat file connection manager, Just double click on Flat file destination component in your Dataflowtask and it will ask you for changing metadata.
Also, it is nice to - first - open your Flat File connection manager and refresh it's settings.